# How to create a mock IWorkbench for testing my Wizard?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Im working on a bigger Eclipse Plugin project, where one of the parts is a custom ImportWizard.

Now i would like to write tests for my wizard code, but to even start testing it i need to create it, for which i require an `IWorkbench`.

The Wizard Code looks like the following:

```java
public class XMLImportWizard extends Wizard implements IImportWizard
{
  XMLImportWizardPage page;

  // Just uses the super constructor

  @Override
  public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection)
  {
    setTitleBarColor(new RGB(0, 73, 144));
  }

  @Override
  public void addPages()
  {
    setWindowTitle("Import");
    page =
        new XMLImportWizardPage("Import");
    addPage(page);
    page.setErrorMessage("");

  }

  @Override
  public boolean performFinish()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Atleast in the `init` method, i require an exisiting `IWorkbench` object.

I have already searched for some way to Mock an Eclipse Workbench but i havent found anything. I havent found a way to create Workbench, at all!
Am i looking for the wrong thing or did i just not look hard enough?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As an aside I don't think anything actually uses the colour set by `setTitleBarColor`

Comment: @greg-449 Ah alright, if i remember right, that was part of the PDE Import Wizard Template Code that got generated.